# imap() - return results in list in R

Tags: r, list, environment-variables, apply

Most of the included code serves reproducibility,my question is regarding the export of results from an `imap()` function.

I have written some functions that aggregate and summarize my data, as below. It creates a list, with multiple lists - one list for every gears.

```
splitCars <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)

summarizeMtcarsYearly <- function(x)
{
  #Ngears
  v1 <- length(unique(x$gear))
  v2 <- paste0(unique(levels(as.factor(x$gear))),collapse = ', ')
  #Build data
  y <- data.frame(Ngears=v1,gears=v2,stringsAsFactors = F)
  return(y)
}

summarizeMtcars <-function(){

  splitCars <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
  splitCars <- lapply(splitCars,summarizeMtcarsYearly)

}

splitCars <- summarizeMtcars()
```

for every gear in the list, i want to create the summary table. I have also written a function for this (below). The details are not important, this is just for reproducibility. The important part of this function is where I export the table to a results folder - **last 5 lines**.

```
createSummaryTable <- function(x, y){
  
  tab <- plot_ly(
    type = 'table',
    header = list(
    values = c(paste0("Gears = "), y, ""),
    align = c('left', rep('center')),
    line = list(width = 1, color = 'black'),
    fill = list(color = 'rgb(235, 100, 230)'),
    font = list(family = "Arial", size = 14, color = "white")
    ),
      cells = list(
      values = rbind(c('number of gears', 'list of gears'),
                     c(x$Ngears, x$gears)),
      align = c('left', rep('center')),
      line = list(color = "black", width = 1),
      fill = list(color = c('rgb(235, 193, 238)', 'rgba(228, 222, 249, 0.65)')),
      font = list(family = "Arial", size = 12, color = c("black"))
    ))
  
  
  test_dir <- "/Users/testFolder"

  tab <- plotly_json(tab, FALSE)
  tabName <- paste0("summaryVariables_gear_TEST", y, ".json" )
  write(tab, paste0(test_dir, "/", tabName))
  
}
```

I pretend not to know how many gears my data will have i am then using `imap()` function to apply a `createSummaryTable` to every element of the list, and exported it directly to a predefined folder:

```
splitCars <- summarizeMtcars()
imap(splitCars, function(x, y) createSummaryTable(x,y))
```

which was working exactly the way i wanted to have it. However, now, i need to return  all the tables for every single gear inside a list, something like this:

```
createSummaryTable <- function(x, y){

  tab <- ... # this is the same as before


  tabname <- paste0("summary_", y)
  assign(tabname, tab)

}

analysis.summaryTables <- function(){
  
  # create tables
    splitCars <- summarizeMtcars()
    imap(splitCars, function(x, y) createSummaryTable(x,y))
  
  # append all tables to one list
  tables <- ls(patter = "summary_")
  out <- do.call(c,list(tables))
  
  
}
```

however when i run this

```
summaryTables <- analysis.summaryTables()
```

summaryTable is just an empty character string.

**How can i store all the output from imap() in a single list in R** ??

how can i access the elements from the function `createSummaryTable` environment and append them together in R?

Comment: in `imap` the second argument is the string of the name. You're using them inverted if I understood correctly from your code.

Comment: i am affraid i do not understand what you mean @Edo. Would you mind explaining in more detail?

Comment: `tabname <- paste0("summary_", x)` shouldn't it be `tabname <- paste0("summary_", y)` ?

Comment: oh, yes of course, you are absolutely right

Comment: Your example is really long just to ask a question on `imap`. Are you sure you can't shorten it down?

Comment: i agree and i tried to reduce it, but then it wouldnt be reproducible anymore. Big portion of the code is data manipulation, which is required in order to apply the imap in the context where i have the question

Comment: it also took me forever to prepare this, as i work on more complex data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you have a function `createSummaryTable` that creates an object, a table to be specific.

You have a list of named dataframe and you want to map this list into your function to return a list of objects (a list of tables to be specific) where their names will be the same but "summary_" has to appear before.

Therefore:

```
createSummaryTable <- function(x, y){

  # do something here

  return(tbl)

}

# map your list
out <- purrr::imap(list_of_named_dataframes, createSummaryTable)
names(out) <- paste("summary", names(out), sep = "_")
```

and `out` is what you're looking for.

Comment: i do need the imap function, because inside the `createSummaryTable` i am using index to name each table

Comment: I changed my answer. But I still believe you should edit the names  of the list separately with `names<-`.

Comment: is the result working for you? I have implemented it, but i get a character vector of 3 elements as result

Comment: oh, my bad ... by leaving out the lat line `names(out) <- paste("summary", names(out), sep = "_")` i get the table, i can work with that. Such a simple solutions!

Comment: if you're putting the last two lines in a wrapping function, you need to write `out` or `return(out)` at the end. Otherwise you will get `names(out)` as output, because that's the last element that was returned invisibly. Watch out for this kind of stuff.

Comment: in case you have any good references where to learn about environments, i am all ears. I always struggle to work with function inside of functions and their elements

Comment: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html. However, your question is not related to environments..